# Promise.all is resolving conditional promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

i have written a function that will either return the input promise of an empty promise based on a condition

```
export const promiseUtility = (promise, condition) => {
  if (condition) {
    return promise;
  } else {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
  }
};
```

when i am calling this function such that

```
    const arr= [
      promiseUtility({
        promise: getUsers(req, type, id),
        condition: req.body.shouldGetUsers
      }),
      promiseUtility({
        promise: getObjects(req, type, id),
        condition: req.body.shouldGetObjects,
    ];

    const [users =[], objects =[]] = await Promise.all(arr)
```

The problem that i am facing is when a condition like `shouldGetUsers` is false, even then the original promise i.e. `getUsers(req)` is getting resolved. It looks like this is because i have called that `getUsers` function. How can i deal with such situation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a promise to resolve, you must not create it in the first place. But you already create a promise when you pass `getUsers(req, type, id)` as the `promise` argument to your `promiseUtility` function.

I suggest you use a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead, which will only execute the `getUsers` function if the condition is true:

```js
const arr = [
  req.body.shouldGetUsers ? getUsers(req, type, id) : Promise.resolve(),
  req.body.shouldGetObjects ? getObjects(req, type, id) : Promise.resolve()
];
```

Comment: Instead of `Promise.resolve()`, you can further simplify to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Heiko's answer. But, i figured out if we want to make a generic utility function for that then we can do it like this.

```
export const promiseUtility = (promise, condition) => {
  if (condition) {
    return promise();
  } else {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
  }
};

const arr= [
  promiseUtility({
    promise: () => getUsers(req, type, id),
    condition: req.body.shouldGetUsers
  }),
  promiseUtility({
    promise: () => getObjects(req, type, id),
    condition: req.body.shouldGetObjects,
  })
];

const [users =[], objects =[]] = await Promise.all(arr)
```

Comment: You should rename the `promise` option. It's not a promise any more, it's a function.

Comment: Tbh, this utility function call is longer, harder to read, and less easy to understand than the ternary expression.